# Unable to Install UBUNTU on asus vivobook X510U dual bootable

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, software-installation, asus

I'm trying to dual boot my ASUS VIVOBOOK X510U and I partitioned my hard drive for that but during installation, partition does not see anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

after starting the setup when it asks "Installation type", look for the option "Something else" and continue. Then on the next screen you will see your created partition. Format/"New Partition Table" the new partition/freespace to ext4 format and set the mount point to "/". Select the primary hard drive for "Device for boot loader installation:". In case you have only single hard drive it will be selected by default. Then continue with the "Install Now". Rest process with be self explanatory.

[image]